# How do I check if a SSLSocket connection is sane on Java?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a SSLSocket pool and I need to check if the socket connection is sane before borrowing the object.

The isConnected, isInputShutdown and isOutputShutdown are useless because they don't check if both sides are connected and if I try to write or read from the socket I might get a SocketException.

Here is my code for testing a connection:

```
if(sslSocket.isConnected() && 
       !sslSocket.isInputShutdown() && 
       !sslSocket.isOutputShutdown()){
    valid = true;
}
```

This code doesn't work, as explained above.

So, what is the best way to check if a SSLSocket (or a regular Socket) is sane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "sane" you mean connected, you can only detect that a TCP socket is disconnected once you've tried to write to it:

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0106.1/1154.html

Hence, you need to make use of the exception accordingly in Java.

Comment: I've tested sending a byte over the connection and catching the exception but it seems that this doesn't test the read operation and I can get an exception while reading later on. I might be wrong on this, will do more tests.

Comment: Same thing, you can't test whether you can read until you read. Between the time you test whether the socket is open and the time you read from it, the remote party may have closed the connection. It may even close it while you're reading.

Comment: Remember, the state of the socket is controlled partially by the peer.  So any check you perform on the local machine is vulnerable to becoming stale nearly immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Would trying to read from the socket and catching a SocketException not be sane enough?

Comment: I can't read from the socket if there is nothing on the socket, that would be blocking. Checking if there is something available on the socket using the available() method from the inputStream is not enough also.

Comment: available() always returns zero for an SSLSocket, but there is the timeout mechanism, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If reading, set a readTimeout via Socket.setSoTimeout() and catch SocketTimeoutException, or write and catch an IOException: connection reset. There are no other mechanisms. The isXXX() APIs you mention only tell you what *you* have done to *this Socket.* They don't tell you anything about the state of the *connection.*

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and here was the fix: Since the **sslSocket** is created from the **sslServerSocket**, closing the server socket instead of the socket will work.

Using the the suggested time out, catching the SSLException, and closing the socket should help to ensure the connection is still valid without the need for threading.

```
sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(sslServerSocketPort);
sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
sslsocket.setSoTimeout(5000);

// Restart connections
if(sslserversocket.isClosed() || sslserversocket == null){
    sslserversocket.close();
    startSSLServer();
}
```